Azure Data factory lookup sorting the data
How to sort data in lookup in azure data factory - pipeline with timestamp?
a solution to sort without any logical apps or functions or dataflow.
I have 10 files with different timestamp, I need to read the data in ascending order.

Could you add more information about source data? What kind of data is that?

To sort your lookup array in the ADF pipeline, you can use the approach from this link by @Nandan Hegde.
I have used the same pipeline JSON from that blog and modified as below to sort it based on the timestamp value.
This is my source csv data:
time,number
2025-05-20T09:34:12.507427Z,1
2024-03-28T09:34:12.507427Z,2
2024-05-27T09:34:12.507437Z,3
2024-02-28T09:34:12.507427Z,4
2024-05-20T09:34:12.507427Z,5

First add your lookup activity at the first and give the output array of the lookup activity @activity('Lookup1').output.value to the sourceArray variable.


Modify the if activity condition inside For-Each activity to suit it for the timestamp value.
@greater(ticks(variables('SourceArray')[int(variables('CurrentItemValue'))].time), ticks(variables('SourceArray')[int(variables('NextItemValue'))].time))


Sorted lookup array after Until activity:

